# Поиск пользователей по полям профиля

Tags: wordpress, поиск

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать поиск пользователей по значениям полей в их профиле?
Есть инсталляция WordPress актуальной версии
Есть BuddyPress для организации расширенного профиля
В расширенный профиль добавлены поля
НЯП для организации запроса используется переменная args и указания на поля.
Как правильно получить имена этих полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как правильно получить имена этих полей?

С помощью функции `get_user_meta`

```
$user_id = 9;
$key = 'nickname';
$single = true;
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, true ); 
echo 'Значение ключа '. $key . ' у пользователя ' . $user_id . ' равно: ' . $user_last; 

// получим:
// Значение ключа nickname у пользователя 9 равно: Enot
```

Полные описание функции см на:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_user_meta

Можно также воспользоваться классом [WP_User](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/)

Comment: Спасибо!  А есть где посмотреть примеры поиска по пользователям?

Comment: @AntonZhitarev https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-profile-search/ и множество до плагинов для этого. У всех код открыт.